# How to decompile a whole Jar file?

Tags: java, jar, decompiler

Does anyone know of a free decompiler that can decompile an entire Jar file instead of a single class? I have a problem with sub classes like name$1.class name$2.class name.class

Comment: Remember two more things: 1) The mere mention of a decompiler will cause the "holier than thou's" to come out and make value judgements about your motives despite having no idea what your planned use is, so be careful who you talk to.  2) The fancy JavaDecompiler will give you an excellent rendition of the code, well laid out and easy to read - missing only comments.  It is astoundingly good, recovering a JAR file which had long lost source complete with variable names.  Of course we don't obfuscate our in-house JAR files.

Comment: See also remarks in post [Choose and test java decompiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898391).

Comment: I've stopped by this thread so many times when I needed to study how someone accomplished something for a Bukkit plugin... That comment always leaves me with a smile. I wish I could upvote it every time I stop by.

Comment: Simple online decompiler if you don't want to download any software. http://www.javadecompilers.com/

Comment: This shouldn't be closed as the decompilers playground changes dynamically. Currently, the best is probably [FernFlower](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/plugins/java-decompiler/engine).

If you're looking for an easy solution, download [Windup](http://windup.jboss.org/) and run it's command-line version on your .jar. It will decompile using FernFlower, with support up to Java 8 (jad only suports up to Java 1.3, JavaDecompiler up to Java 1.5 IIRC), with a fallback to Procyon if FernFlower fails.

Comment: As of 2022, this one works well: https://jdec.app/

Comment: As of 2022, [**QuiltMC/quiltflower**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/647140/6309) looks promising.

Answer (score 373, accepted):

2023: [splashout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048376/splashout) suggests in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647116/how-to-decompile-a-whole-jar-file/647140?noredirect=1#comment135449931_647140) the [`Vineflower/vineflower`](https://github.com/Vineflower/vineflower) decompiler ([releases](https://github.com/Vineflower/vineflower/releases)), renaming from Quiltflower to Vineflower.

```bash
java -jar vineflower.jar -dgs=1 c:\Temp\binary\library.jar c:\Temp\souce
```

---

2022 update: [**QuiltMC/quiltflower**](https://github.com/QuiltMC/quiltflower) is the latest [most advanced Java decompiler](https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/ue8u59/new_open_source_java_decompiler/):

Quiltflower is a modern, general purpose decompiler focused on improving code quality, speed, and usability.
Quiltflower is a fork of [Fernflower](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/plugins/java-decompiler/engine) and Forgeflower.

> Changes include:
>
> - New language features (Try with resources, switch expressions, pattern matching, and more)
> - Better control flow generation (loops, try-catch, and switch, etc.)
> - More configurability
> - Better error messages
> - Javadoc application
> - Multithreading
> - Optimization
> - Many other miscellaneous features and fixes
>
> Originally intended just for use with the QuiltMC toolchain with Minecraft, Quiltflower quickly expanded to be a general purpose java decompiler aiming to create code that is as accurate and clean as possible.
>
> If the name sounds familiar it's because Quiltflower is a fork of [Fernflower](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/plugins/java-decompiler/engine), the (in)famous decompiler that was developed by Stiver, maintained by Jetbrains, and became the default decompiler in Intellij IDEA.
> Fernflower also quickly found its way into many other tools.
>
> Over the past year, Quiltflower has added support for features such as modern string concatenation, a code formatter, sealed classes, pattern matching, switch expressions, try-with-resources, and more. Quiltflower also focuses on the code quality of the decompiled output, and takes readability very seriously.

See [output examples](https://gist.github.com/SuperCoder7979/c7171b0e34b6eccf0b9f1c37030867dc).

> Runs nice with [jbang](https://www.jbang.dev/)
>
> ```
> https://github.com/QuiltMC/quiltflower/releases/download/1.8.1/quiltflower-1.8.1.jar
> ```

Or:

> ```
> java -jar quiltflower.jar -dgs=1 c:\Temp\binary\library.jar c:\Temp\binary\Boot.class c:\Temp\source\
> ```

---

2009: [JavaDecompiler](https://java-decompiler.github.io/) can do a good job with a jar: since 0.2.5, All files, in JAR files, are displayed.

[image: http://java.decompiler.free.fr/sites/default/screenshots/screenshot1.png]

See also [the question "How do I “decompile” Java class files?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535/how-do-i-decompile-java-class-files/272595#272595).

The JD-Eclipse doesn't seem to have changed since late 2009 though (see [Changes](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=changes/jdeclipse)).
So its integration with latest Eclipse (3.8, 4.2+) might be problematic.

JD-Core is actively maintained.

Both are the result of the fantastic work of (SO user) [**Emmanuel Dupuy**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/37785/emmanuel-dupuy).

---

2018: A more modern option, mentioned [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647116/how-to-decompile-a-whole-jar-file/647140?noredirect=1#comment89196907_647140) by [David Kennedy Araujo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1697026/david-kennedy-araujo):

[**JetBrains/intellij-community/plugins/java-decompiler/engine**](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/plugins/java-decompiler/engine)

> Fernflower is the first actually working analytical decompiler for Java and probably for a high-level programming language in general.
>
> ```
> java -jar fernflower.jar [-<option>=<value>]* [<source>]+ <destination>
>
> java -jar fernflower.jar -hes=0 -hdc=0 c:\Temp\binary\ -e=c:\Java\rt.jar c:\Temp\source\
> ```

See also [How to decompile to java files intellij idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389006/how-to-decompile-to-java-files-intellij-idea) for a command working with recent IntelliJ IDEA.

---

2022 update: [Florian Wendelborn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2857873/florian-wendelborn) suggests in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647116/how-to-decompile-a-whole-jar-file?noredirect=1#comment126287968_647116)

> this one works well: [jdec.app](https://jdec.app/) from [Leonardo Santos](https://github.com/leonardosnt).

Comment: fyi, java decompiler works on windows, mac and linux.

Comment: @AlexS nice :) Next step: version control (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59561/what-tools-techniques-can-benefit-a-solo-developer) And then Continuous Integration (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130592/is-continuous-integration-important-for-a-solo-developer)

Comment: Anyone get the eclipse plugin to work anymore with the latest eclipse and jdk7? I tried but I get a download error. JD-Gui works but jd-eclipse seems to fail for me...

Comment: @StephaneGrenier I didn't test it recently. That could be a question in its own (detailed with the OS, Eclipse version, and screenshot of the error message you got, or the Eclipse log view). Java-Decompiler maintainer Emmanuel Dupuy (http://stackoverflow.com/users/37785/emmanuel-dupuy) could answer.

Comment: so with plugin for Eclipse how can I view code for a specific jar in Package Explorer?

Comment: With Java Decompiler you can open the JAR file and go to File, Save All Sources. It saves all class files into java files =D

Comment: Please remember that it makes errors too.  I have a class with a Member variable and it moved it to the parameter of a function, destroying the effect of the code.  Watch out, it will get you.

Comment: jd.benow.ca is currently down. However, the Internet Archive has a snapshot of it from January: https://web.archive.org/web/20140105052622/http://jd.benow.ca/

Comment: @CharlesW I think this was an optimisation done by the compiler, not by the decompiler...

Comment: Is there any way to prevent from my code to be decompiled ? If I store sensitive information inside the CLASS files

Comment: Doesn't work if you only have Java 8 installed on your system.

Comment: JD is a good starting point but fail to decompile complex code.
A good alternative is use https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/plugins/java-decompiler/engine

Comment: @DavidKennedyAraujo Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Is there a download location for fernflower.jar?

Comment: @Saftpresse99 Maybe http://www.javadecompilers.com/? or https://github.com/fesh0r/fernflower (but requiring a compilation)

Comment: Quick answer: Get the complied code that uses Java 17 here: https://github.com/Vineflower/vineflower/releases.  Use command: java -jar vineflower.jar -dgs=1 c:\Temp\binary\library.jar c:\Temp\souce

Comment: @splashout Thank you for the update. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 41):

First of all, it's worth remembering that all Java archive files (`.jar`/`.war`/etc...) are **all basically just fancy`.zip` files**, with a few added manifests and metadata.

Second, to tackle this problem I personally use several tools which handle this problem on all levels:

- [**Jad**](https://varaneckas.com/jad/) + [**Jadclipse**](http://jadclipse.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) while working in IDE for decompiling `.class` files
- [**WinRAR**](http://www.rarlab.com/), my favorite compression tool natively supports Java archives (again, see first paragraph).
- [**Beyond Compare**](http://www.scootersoftware.com/), my favorite diff tool, when configured correctly can do on-the-fly comparisons between any archive file, including `jar`s. Well worth a try.

The advantage of all the aforementioned, is that I do not need to hold any other external tool which clutters my work environment. Everything I will ever need from one of those files can be handled inside my IDE or diffed with other files natively.

Answer (score 38):

If you happen to have both a bash shell and jad:

```
JAR=(your jar file name)
unzip -d $JAR.tmp $JAR
pushd $JAR.tmp
for f in `find . -name '*.class'`; do
    jad -d $(dirname $f) -s java -lnc $f
done
popd
```

I might be a tiny, tiny bit off with that, but it should work more or less as advertised.  You should end up with `$JAR.tmp` containing your decompiled files.

Comment: on ubuntu use #!/bin/bash  instead of #!/bin/sh becausw pushd doesnt work for the default ubuntu shell...

Comment: I'm using `javap` within this basic loop structure, and it's working for me.

Comment: @mossplix or use /bin/sh (more portable) with `cd` and `cd -`, which is enough for this use case :-)

Answer (score 28):

I have had reasonable success with a tool named (frustratingly) "[JD: Java Decompiler](http://java-decompiler.github.io/)".

I have found it better than most decompilers *when dealing with classes compiled for Java 5 and higher*. Unfortunately, it can still have some hiccups where JAD would normally succeed.

Comment: I couldn't download Windows or Linux version of JD-GUI. Is this problem only appears to me?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen I deleted it. Thank you for notifying it. Lets keep answers clean :)

Answer (score 14):

Something like:

```
jar -xf foo.jar && find . -iname "*.class" | xargs /opt/local/bin/jad -r
```

maybe?

Comment: I've used jad for a while and needed a quick way to extract and decompile a whole jar. Thanks, this helped immensely.

Comment: Worked immediately

Answer (score 5):

Insert the following into decompile.jar.sh

```
# Usage: decompile.jar.sh some.jar [-d]

# clean target folders
function clean_target {
  rm -rf $unjar $src $jad_log
}

# clean all debug stuff
function clean_stuff {
  rm -rf $unjar $jad_log
}

# the main function
function work {
  jar=$1
  unjar=`basename $jar.unjar`
  src=`basename $jar.src`
  jad_log=jad.log

  clean_target

  unzip -q $jar -d $unjar
  jad -d $src -ff -r -lnc -o -s java $unjar/**/*.class > $jad_log 2>&1

  if [ ! $debug ]; then
    clean_stuff
  fi

  if [ -d $src ] 
    then
      echo "$jar has been decompiled to $src"
    else
      echo "Got some problems check output or run in debug mode"
  fi
}

function usage {
  echo "This script extract and decompile JAR file"
  echo "Usage: $0 some.jar [-d]"
  echo "    where: some.jar is the target to decompile"
  echo "    use -d for debug mode"
}

# check params
if [ -n "$1" ]
  then
    if [ "$2" == "-d" ]; then
      debug=true
      set -x
    fi
    work $1
  else
    usage
fi
```

- chmod +x decomplie.jar.sh //executable
- ln -s ./decomplie.jar.s /usr/bin/dj

Ready to use, just type `dj your.jar` and you will get `your.jar.src` folder with sources. Use `-d` option for debug mode.

Comment: Thanks, but had to change "jad" to "./jad" on line 23 and run "bash decompile.jar.sh foo.jar -d" as I did not want to pollute my bin folder

Comment: any recompiler ? recompiles jad files into jar ?

Answer (score 1):

**Note: This solution only works for Mac and *nix users.**

I also tried to find Jad with no luck. My quick solution was to download [MacJad](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Development/Compilers/MacJAD.shtml) that contains jad. Once you downloaded it you can find jad in [where-you-downloaded-macjad]/MacJAD/Contents/Resources/jad.

Answer (score 0):

You extract it and then use jad against the dir.

Comment: I don't think you can just run it against the dir. You will have to specify {dir}/**/*.class

Comment: Extract the jar and use something like jad {dir}, I have just tested it and doesn't work on windows