# Eclipse how to see the Java file instead of class file

Tags: java, eclipse, class

I want to see the java file when i click the respective object or it's method. I knew that java files are compiled and it will be in the .class format. Is it anyway to see as a java file in eclipse by using plugins or Anyother tool is there to achieve this? So we can avoid to see the implementation of the object and it's method in the java portal's..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [eclipse > java > open linked resources sources (.java instead of .class )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603292/eclipse-java-open-linked-resources-sources-java-instead-of-class)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the source available then use [Attach Source](http://www.cavdar.net/2008/07/14/3-ways-of-jdk-source-code-attachment-in-eclipse/) feature. If not then any decompiler eclipse plugin is fine. My preference is [JD-Eclipse](http://jd.benow.ca/).

Answer (score 3):

If you have the source code, you can attach it so that it gets opened automatically. This is explained in [Is there an easy way to attach source in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122160/is-there-an-easy-way-to-attach-source-in-eclipse)

If you don't have access to the source, you can integrate a Java decompiler into Eclipse: [Java Decompiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375037/java-decompiler)

Comment: The JD is not working. I'm using the indigo version of eclipse. What i can do ? If i want to attache the source Where i have to look in my disk? My java installed location?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the source of the library (jar) you can add it (in the properties) of the jar, otherwise you can use "decompiler" plugin: http://java.decompiler.free.fr/