# Is there a tool to reverse engineer a java.class file?

Tags: java

I am in jam.   I accidentally rm a java file I have worked on for several days.
There is no back up for it.   I do however still have the .class file around.

I need
some tool to reverse engineer this code.  It does not have to be really good tool.

I just need something to remind me enough of what I did and I fill in the rest.  Is there such tool ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAD_(JAva_Decompiler), it won't give you clear source back, but it will help a bit.

Comment: http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui.

Comment: So in the future you'll be using source control? ;)

Comment: may be u should see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671394/where-can-i-find-a-java-decompiler

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I was about to say the same :)

Comment: The question [Java decompiler](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4375037/214178) discusses couple more options and an Eclipse plugin option.

Comment: It can't help you either, reverse engineering requires skills other than coding java and time spent to return code back double or triple.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[JD-GUI](http://jd.benow.ca/#jd-online) is pretty good and should help you out.

Comment: Ok, thank JD-GUI seems to work   I still need to do some work but this is good enough.   And yes, I do have source control unfortunately I could not check in the code because it was not complete.  This is just a case of the fingers were to fast for the brain.