# how can i find the files imported in a java class?

Tags: java

I don't get to see the source code but the .class file.
Can I still find out the files that are imported?

Comment: What do you mean by "imported"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind that imports are simply a convenience mechanism that lets the Java developer refer to a class using it's simple name (`Date`) rather than it's Fully Qualified Name (FQN - `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date`).

So if you run the `.class` file [through a decompiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898391/choose-and-test-java-decompiler), you'll likely see references using the FQN and possibly no import statements.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you just want to do it manually, I suggest you take a look at a decompiler such as JD GUI

Otherwise, you need to go the reflection way if you want this information programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this in batch, and do not want to bother with all the other details that a decompiler would offer, you can inspect the constant pool for class references.

Beware that, as previously mentioned, source imports are merely a convenience and do not correspond directly to anything in class files. Scanning the constant pool will *not* show unused imports from the source file, and it will *not* show classes used only for compile-time constants (`public static final String ...` and the like). It *will* show FQNs even for classes in the same package, and it *will* show classes referred to using FQN without an import. It *will* show classes whose signatures are used implicitly:

```
URL loc = Something.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
```

will produce references to `ProtectionDomain` and `CodeSource` in bytecode even though the source did not explicitly mention them.

https://hg.netbeans.org/core-main/raw-file/default/nbbuild/antsrc/org/netbeans/nbbuild/VerifyClassLinkage.java is an example of how to do this scan (see the `dependencies` method).