# How to Decompile a java package?

Tags: java, eclipse

how to decompile a whole package that contains Java classes?
indeed the file is .war and under src/ there are packages that I can not open.
is there a plugin like JadClipse for packages? thank you :)

Comment: http://java.decompiler.free.fr/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to decompile a whole Jar file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647116/how-to-decompile-a-whole-jar-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to decompile a whole Jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647116/how-to-decompile-a-whole-jar-file)

JavaDecompiler can do a good job with a jar: since 0.2.5, All files, in JAR files, are displayed.

Comment: thank you Achintya Jha for your answer, in fact the file is .war and under src/ there are packages that I can not open