# Atmosphere framework Spring mvc integration

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, atmosphere

I am trying to integrate Atmosphere framework with Spring MVC

the samples war files given here 
http://async-io.org/download.html don't contain the .java files in the src folder.

I also went through the other integration examples 
http://keaplogik.blogspot.com/2012/05/atmosphere-websockets-comet-with-spring.html

I am having some problem connecting with twitter when reading through this article.

A. Is there a simpler example somewhere? with explanation like a hello world.

B. How do I get the java files of the sample war file?

I would really appreciate any help Thanks :)

Comment: I think you may be able to get java files from war or jar file by [decomiple it][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647116/how-to-decompile-a-whole-jar-file

Comment: do you mean by integration autowiring or something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote an example on how to integrate Atmosphere framework into Spring framework with usage of websocket protocol and long-polling as fallback protocol. You can find it on [GitHub](https://github.com/GregaVrbancic/spring-atmosphere-chat-example).

As a matter of second question the answer in no. You can't get the java files out of war packages. War packages contains of compiled java classes, resource files, xml configuration files, etc.

Comment: Hi, the example doesn't works with spring security, do you have any clue, Regards

Comment: Hi, sorry for late feedback. Can you write more precisely about the problem you encounter?

Comment: Hi. When trying to Package your project, i get error: [ERROR] /home/roman/git/spring-atmosphere-chat-example/src/main/java/tk/gregsource/app/AtmosphereController.java:[22,55] error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6. Can you please suggest why would that be? STS 3.6.0, maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1 integrated in STS.

Comment: I have both java 7 and 8 versions in my Ubuntu. /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67/bin/javac and /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_20/bin/javac

Comment: I got that. maven-compiler-plugin in POM.XML was configured to 1.6.