# Is it possible to decompile a Jenkins plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins plugin file (.hpi file) and I need some way to "decompile" it to see its contents. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to decompile a whole Jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647116/how-to-decompile-a-whole-jar-file)

You're likely going to have a rough time... I'd advise you look for the source.

Comment: I renamed the .hpi file to .jar and opened it in JD-GUI. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Most Jenkins plugins are open-source and the source code is readily available