# How to decompile to java files intellij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, decompiling

IDEA has a great built-in feature - decompiler. It works great.I can copy source code, but I cannot find option to extract all decompiled java classes to java files.
This project has a lot of java classes and packages, so I will be to long to copy this manually.
Does anyone know how to extract to java source files.
  Thx

Comment: [Look Inside Compiled Code with Java Bytecode Decompiler](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/03/java-bytecode-decompiler/) -- This page introduced the plugin `Java Bytecode Decompiler` in 2020.03. By using this bundled plugin inside Intellij, it's pretty easy to decompile `.jar` to java code.

Answer (score 97):

As of August 2017 and IntelliJ V2017.2, the accepted answer does not seem to be entirely accurate anymore: there is no `fernflower.jar` to use.

The jar file is called `java-decompiler.jar` and does not include a main manifest... Instead you can use the following command (from a Mac install):

```
java -cp "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/java-decompiler/lib/java-decompiler.jar" org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.main.decompiler.ConsoleDecompiler
```

(you will get the wrong *Usage* command, but it does work).

Comment: Merging this answer with the top comment from the accepted answer, the command to launch to use the same params that IDEA uses by default is `java -cp "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/java-decompiler/lib/java-decompiler.jar" org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.main.decompiler.ConsoleDecompiler -hdc=0 -dgs=1 -rsy=1 -rbr=1 -lit=1 -nls=1 -mpm=60 /absolute/path/to/src1 /absolute/path/to/src2 /absolute/path/to/dst`

Comment: On Arch install: java -cp "/usr/share/idea/plugins/java-decompiler/lib/java-decompiler.jar" org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.main.decompiler.ConsoleDecompiler -hdc=0 -dgs=1 -rsy=1 -rbr=1 -lit=1 -nls=1 -mpm=60 /absolute/path/to/src1 /absolute/path/to/src2 /absolute/path/to/dst

Comment: This more brief command worked for me (based on these answers and the usage note): java -cp <path>/java-decompiler/lib/java-decompiler.jar org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.main.decompiler.ConsoleDecompiler -dgs=true <target.jar> <dest>

Comment: Windows **decompile.cmd** scr1 src2 dst: `java -cp "%ProgramFiles%\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3\plugins\java-decompiler\lib\java-decompiler.jar" org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.main.decompiler.ConsoleDecompiler -hdc=0 -dgs=1 -rsy=1 -rbr=1 -lit=1 -nls=1 -mpm=60 %*`

Comment: how could you read what intellij is using as params? i didn't find these info here https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/plugins/java-decompiler/engine

Comment: @ahmed_khan_89 by decompiling the decompiler bruh

Answer (score 53):

Follow instructions for [IntelliJ JD plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/plugins/java-decompiler/engine). Or see an excerpt from the instructions below.

```
java -jar fernflower.jar [<source>]+ <destination>
```

> `+` means 1 or more times
>   `<source>`: file or directory with files to be decompiled. Directories are recursively scanned. Allowed file extensions are class, zip and jar.
>   `<destination>`: destination directory

Example:

```
java -jar fernflower.jar -hdc=0 -dgs=1 -rsy=1 -lit=1 c:\Temp\binary\ -e=c:\Java\rt.jar c:\Temp\source\
```

Be aware that if you pass it a ".jar" file for the source, it will create another ".jar" file in the destination, however, within the new ".jar" file, the files will be .java instead of .class files (it doesn't explode the jar).

---

#### UPDATE

People ask me: How do I get the fernflower.jar?

If you have any IntelliJ product installed, chances are that you already have the Fernflower decompiler on your computer. IntelliJ IDEA comes with [Java Bytecode Decompiler](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7100-java-decompiler-intellij-plugin) plugin (bundled) which is a modern extension of Fernflower.

1. Locate the file in `${IntelliJ_INSTALL_DIR}\plugins\java-decompiler\lib\java-decompiler.jar` (example: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018\plugins\java-decompiler\lib).
2. Copy it somewhere and rename to fernflower.jar (optional).
3. This JAR is not executable, so we can't run it using `java -jar`. However something like this works:

   ```
   java -cp fernflower.jar org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.main.decompiler.ConsoleDecompiler [<source>]+ <destination>
   ```

   `org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.main.decompiler.ConsoleDecompiler` is the class that contains the main method to run the decompiler.

   Example:

   ```
   mkdir output_src
   java -cp fernflower.jar org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.main.decompiler.ConsoleDecompiler -hdc=0 -dgs=1 -rsy=1 -lit=1 ./input.jar ./output_src
   ```

If you don't have IntelliJ products installed, either download it now (available on [jetbrains.com](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download)) or make your own decompiler executable from sources (available on [Github](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/plugins/java-decompiler/engine)).

Comment: How do I get the fernflower.jar ?

Comment: @naXa: Really? Like how many actually useful .jars did turn up, when googleing? Not so many, actually...

Comment: @Make42 I didn't get it. Well, fernflower is an open source project. It means everyone can package a jar for himself.

Comment: Note that this produces sources JARs which would then have to be unpacked to view the decompiled Java files. You can unpack them with a one liner in bash `find ./yoursourcesdirectory -name '*.jar' -exec sh -c 'unzip -d "${1%.*}" "$1"' _ {} \;`

Comment: I did install the plugin, but I cannot find anything...

Comment: @Madeo where did you look?

Comment: in the plugins folder of Intellij, but it's ok, I have used JDGUI.

Comment: Quick answer: Get the complied code that uses Java 17 here: https://github.com/Vineflower/vineflower/releases.  Use command: java -jar vineflower.jar -dgs=1 c:\Temp\binary\library.jar c:\Temp\souce

Answer (score 22):

1. Open an existing project or create a new one.
2. Go to [Project structure settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-settings-and-structure.html) > Libraries. Add the jar you want to decompile in libraries by clicking the `+` symbol.
3. Go to the [Project tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-tool-window.html) shown on the left. Search for jar name that you added in the previous step. Navigate to the desired class or package.

You can see the decompiled java files for that jar.

Comment: surprised this doesn't have even more votes because this is probably what most people actually are looking to do.

Comment: Downvoted - doesn't answer the question of getting to source files. @NicholasDiPiazza Not necessarily -- it only allows you to browse and only one file at a time. To get source, you would have to copy/paste from the editor window into a new .java file. Not fun when you have 50 or 100 class files you need the source for.

Comment: Works thanks! Now how do I make it editable or move it to my actual intelliJ workspace?

Comment: you can right-click on jar file and choose the option "Add as Library..." - then IDE will allow to browse its content

Comment: strange, I did that with a Minecraft mod jar I want to examine (deobfuscated, of course) and there is no button to expand and explore the jar?

Comment: it is in my libraries, but I'm not able to get the classes even, not the source code...

Answer (score 5):

You could use one of these (you can both use them online or download them, there is some info about each of them) :
http://www.javadecompilers.com/

The one IntelliJ IDEA uses is fernflower, but it can't handle recent things - like String/Enum switches, generics (didn't test this one personally, only read about it), ...
I just tried cfr from the above website and the result was the same as with the built-in decompiler (except for the Enum switch I had in my class).

Answer (score 3):

The decompiler of IntelliJ IDEA was not built with this kind of usage in mind. It is only meant to help programmers peek at the bytecode of the java classes that they are developing. For decompiling lots of class files of which you do not have source code, you will need some other java decompiler, which is specialized for this job, and most likely runs standalone, like jad, fernflower, etc.

Comment: but I have copied manually code and it works. Maybe there is any way to do this automaticly or write script to copy from decompiled archive to the project

Comment: See my 2022 UPDATE answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try

https://github.com/fesh0r/fernflower

Command :

```
java -jar fernflower.jar -hes=0 -hdc=0 C:\binary  C:\source
```

Place your jar file in folder C:\binary and source will be extracted and packed in a jar inside C:\source.

Enjoy!

Comment: jar url says not found

Comment: although i could not download the jar from the given link, i was able to follow the usage instructions here to help solve my problem.

i was able to get+use the JAR from my intellij installation. `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.1.5\plugins\java-decompiler\lib\java-decompiler.jar`

Answer (score 2):

Some time ago I used JAD (JAva Decompiler) to achieve this - I do not think IntelliJ's decompiler was incorporated with exporting in mind. It is more of a tool to help look through classes where sources are not available.

JAD is still available for download, but I do not think anyone maintains it anymore: http://varaneckas.com/jad/

There were numerous plugins for it, namely Jadclipse (you guessed it, a way to use JAD in Eclipse - see decompiled classes where code is not available :)).

Comment: Intellij decompiler works great in comparison with other tools, but sometimes it cannot decompile lamdas, so it lefts invokedynamic, but I have tried cfr , and it does it well, but other code not as good as intellij , so I have to copy all code manually (

Answer (score 1):

I use JD-GUI for extract all decompiled java classes to java files.

Comment: Doesn't install on linux

Comment: Doesn't say how to do it in intellij.

Answer (score 1):

Someone had gave good answers. I made another instruction clue step by step.
First, open your studio and search. You can find the decompier is Fernflower.

[image]

Second, we can find it in the plugins directory.

```
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/java-decompiler/lib/java-decompiler.jar
```

Third, run it, you will get the usage

```
java -cp "/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/java-decompiler/lib/java-decompiler.jar" org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.main.decompiler.ConsoleDecompiler

Usage: java -jar fernflower.jar [-<option>=<value>]* [<source>]+ <destination>
Example: java -jar fernflower.jar -dgs=true c:\my\source\ c:\my.jar d:\decompiled\
```

Finally, The studio's nest options for decompiler list as follows according IdeaDecompiler.kt

-hdc=0  -dgs=1  -rsy=1 -rbr=1  -lit=1  -nls=1 -mpm=60 -lac=1

```
IFernflowerPreferences.HIDE_DEFAULT_CONSTRUCTOR to "0",
        IFernflowerPreferences.DECOMPILE_GENERIC_SIGNATURES to "1",
        IFernflowerPreferences.REMOVE_SYNTHETIC to "1",
        IFernflowerPreferences.REMOVE_BRIDGE to "1",
        IFernflowerPreferences.LITERALS_AS_IS to "1",
        IFernflowerPreferences.NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR to "1",
        **IFernflowerPreferences.BANNER to BANNER,**
        IFernflowerPreferences.MAX_PROCESSING_METHOD to 60,
        **IFernflowerPreferences.INDENT_STRING to indent,**
        **IFernflowerPreferences.IGNORE_INVALID_BYTECODE to "1",**
        IFernflowerPreferences.VERIFY_ANONYMOUS_CLASSES to "1",
         **IFernflowerPreferences.UNIT_TEST_MODE to if (ApplicationManager.getApplication().isUnitTestMode) "1" else "0")**
```

I cant find the sutialbe option for the asterisk items.

Hope these steps will make the question clear.

Answer (score 1):

### 2022 UPDATE

Like any experienced developer who's being honest, I have to admit it -- I'm lazy. More is less and less is better when it comes to typing. The answers from @naXa and @yan are fine, except for having to open a terminal and type :-(

To decompile a jar right from within intellij, create a reusable `JAR Application` run configuration:

1. Copy `java-decompiler.jar` to a folder in your project (I used lib). Get from:: Windows: C:\Program Files\Intellij\plugins\java-decompiler\lib; [or from github (documentation is here)](https://github.com/javaweb-sec/fernflower-decomplier)
2. Copy source jar or class files to same folder
3. Create a run configuration with settings like these:

- `Path to JAR:` browse to java-decompiler.jar
- `Program arguments:` -hdc=0 -dgs=1 -rsy=1 -lit=1 your.jar lib
- `Working directory:` lib
- `JRE:` 11

In this case, `your.jar` is the source and `lib` is the output directory. Save it, run it, and watch it do its thing :-)

Need to do it again with different class files or jars? Duplicate the run config and update `Program arguments`.

Comment: Where does this java-decompiler.jar come from?

Comment: @DaveAnkin Updated answer with two locations.

Comment: Quick vineflower answer: Get the complied code that uses Java 17 here: https://github.com/Vineflower/vineflower/releases.  Use command: java -jar vineflower.jar -dgs=1 c:\Temp\binary\library.jar c:\Temp\souce

Answer (score 0):

---- package jar (java) jar -cvfM0 test.jar

- ---Decompile jar(class)>>>>>>>>>jar(java) java -cp "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1\plugins\java-decompiler\lib\java-decompiler.jar" org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.main.decompiler.ConsoleDecompiler -dgs=true C:\ Users\luo\Desktop\sf1\pxks\test.jar C:\Users\luo\Desktop\sf1

Unzip manually

Or use the following command to decompress

find the path
cd..

decompress
jar -xvf test.jar

Reference http://t.csdn.cn/3YLK4

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).