# Way to generate javadoc and java project from jar file

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I use Netbeans. I can make long java projects and then compile them to create a jar file which i can execute independently. But given a jar field, can someone tell how i can generate a java project from it and also its java-doc? Is there an available software that does it or can it be done form within IDE?

It's like saying i have written a C++ code to make an .exe file and wish to do something to extract the C++ source files and headers back from the .exe file. Can that be done?

Comment: You can try opening the `jar` files using a file archiver and extracting the `class` files. You could then use a Java decompiler such as Cavaj to attempt to retrieve some meaningful source code.

Comment: thx, all the comments and answers have helped me a lot. I will randomly choose a right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually i have another way to do it i think i couldn't found a way to do it by netbeans, but the best way that i founded was using [Java Decompiler](http://jd.benow.ca/) i has an option save all sources, create a java empty project in netbeans and then add the source there[image].

Comment: By sources, you mean .java files or .class files or both?

Comment: @userxigement source files in java are .java files

Comment: .java files, actually this application convert class files to java files and you can export them. just you need to give him a jar file

Answer (score 0):

Nop, you can't. I am assuming the documentation you are talking about is in the comments (javadocs): The comments stay in the source files and not in the artifacts.

Nonetheless, You can try reverse engineering for your jar: [How to decompile a whole Jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647116/how-to-decompile-a-whole-jar-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can always **try** to decompile the code. By extracting the `.class` files from the `jar` then running the `.class` files through a decompiler.. However depending on how reputable the decompiler is, there is no guarantee that, that is exactly the code that was used. Also in terms of `javadocs`, if the decompiler is able to extract the javadoc comments I am sure you can then create a `javadoc`. However if it can not then you are out of luck besides making your own `javadoc` of the decompiled code.