# Open Source Continuous Integration tool for solo developer [Java]

Tags: java, open-source, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery

Observed the advantages of CI for solo developers [Is Continuous Integration important for a solo developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130592/is-continuous-integration-important-for-a-solo-developer)

Is there any CI server suitable for solo developers?

They usually consume a lot of RAM and are server-agent based.

In my thinking, they need to be: 
-lightweight (RAM) 
-simple
-compatible with GitHub

Could you quote me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use jenkins/hudson? It is excellent you can configure it with sonar, codestyle, automatic build on every commit and many plugins.

Jenkins comes with an standalone jar file that you can use.

Yes, it's true that it consumes memory but it worth it and it isn't terrible memory consumer.

By the way, you can find here an interesting list:
http://www.opensourcecontinuousintegration.com/

You can take a look and see which one fits your needs.